# Make actions on form1 close

Tags: c#

I was trying to save a file in the end of the program

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{ tabelaEC0.WriteXml(currentdirectory , XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);   
  Application.Exit();
 }
```

In this case it simply doesnt save the file (tried with another button and worked perfectly) So the problem is the Form1 close, any hint?

Update:::

I created an aditional method to save the file, like

```
public void funcaofecho(EventArgs e)

    {table.WriteXml(@"C:/file.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); }
```

And so i'm hooking it on the FormClosing

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{ Form1.Close() += funcaofecho; }
```

I believe this is how it was supposed to work, but it lacks an "object reference"
any hint?

Comment: Please make sure you're using the correct language tag. That code isn't C, and shouldn't have been tagged as such.

Comment: Step through with a debugger and see what exactly happens in WriteXml.  Also, check whether an Exception is thrown when WriteXml is called from FormClosed.

Comment: @computerfreaker I probably misclicked, I'm sorry.

Comment: @EricJ I'm not experienced enough to handle that, but i will tinker around it a while, i will come back with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using tabelaEC0 Which I presume is a control in your form. If this is the case then the control has been destroyed because the form is closed already when that event is fired.

Try to do it at Form_Closing.

Comment: actually i inserted all the table again after `private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)`  so, i'm not sure if it was really destroyed, what is Form_closing? @Gusman

Comment: It's an event, like Closed but it fires before the form gets really closed. And if your control is destroyed it may interfer in its proper execution and adding again the table will not work.

Comment: What if instead of `Application.Exit` i use `System.Environment.Exit(0);` ? The FormClosed will fire up anyways and it wont save the table? @Gusman

Comment: You should not do neither, if this is your only form, when it's closed the process will terminate. Also, you must hook to the event in some way, using the designer (search for FormClosing in events list and double click) or adding **this.FormClosing += (functionname)**. The function sholud look like     **private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)**

Comment: But i have to be able to close it somehow, I created a "exit" button and used the same process, and it actually saves the file correctly, it has `System.Environment.Exit(0)` in the end. Yes, i found the FormClosing exactly like that on msdn and i will try it. Using the FormClosing is similar to `this.FormClosing += (functionname)` ? I dont understand what it means to hook events in anyway, do you know any reference about it that a beginner could read?

Comment: To close your form use this.Close() and here is ms tutorial for events and beginners http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i understand now what you meant by hooking, i'm supposed to create another function with the file write, that the closing process will call, however i still didnt got the hang of it, do you mind taking a look at the update? @Gusman

Comment: This.close is a function, not an event so you cannot hook, yo can hook to this.FormClosing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51141/discussion-between-cesar-amorim-and-gusman)